# How to interpret RI-CLPM parameter estimates when means of variables decrease over time

Tags: interpretation, panel-data, structural-equation-modeling

For a study, I ran an RI-CLPM over 4 time points, looking at the bidirectional association between negative social interactions (X) and depression (Y) over these 4 time points, with cross-lagged parameters constrained to be equal across time. Fit was excellent and parameter estimates for my cross-lagged paths suggested that higher within-person X (negative social interactions) at a previous time point predicted higher within-person Y (depression) at subsequent time point (so a positive relationship). These variables were not significantly related at the between-person level. Seemed simple enough to interpret at first. However, when looking at the descriptive statistics of my sample, the overall means of X and Y decrease over time. For example, negative interaction mean scores in my overall sample were 10 at T1, 8 at T2, 7 at T3 etc., and the same for depression scores. We wonder if this is possibly due to regression to the mean or an effect of being assessed.

I am somewhat confused about how to interpret my findings. Given that the overall means of variables are decreasing over time, can I still interpret my results in this way: that when a person reports more X (e.g., negative social interactions) than they usually do, they also report more Y (e.g., depression) than they usually do at a subsequent time point, so kind of like an exacerbation effect. Or is this not actually representative of the data, and if so, is the correct interpretation: given that the sample means of X (negative social interactions) and Y (depression) seem to go down over time (e.g., a sort of recovery effect), that a "positive" cross-lagged path is actually showing some sort of stunting of this recovery effect.

So I guess more broadly, I'm wondering what a "positive" within-person relationship might actually mean when the overall means of the variables are trending down over time. Hopefully this makes sense and happy to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the RI-CLPM is fit to the data with a saturated mean structure (i.e., estimate a mean at each time-point). So you can interpret your estimates in the way you are doing it as long as there are no between-person differences in the change you are observing. To be on a safer side, you can fit an extension of the RI-CLPM called LCM-SR (latent curve model with structured residuals) which basically add a linear growth factor to the intercept factor (see [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4067471/)).

Kind regards, S.